# Form styling show on focus

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I am trying to style a form - so that the label only shows once a user has written in information.

http://jsfiddle.net/8YqN2/200/

the hover variant works, but not this focus

```
$('input').focus(
  function(){
    $(this).prev().addClass('focus');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).prev().removeClass('focus');
  }
);
```

//start phase

[image]

//entered phase

[image]

Comment: `focus` does not include actually typing anything in. It only indicates that the element now has `focus`. I'm unclear on what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So use a keyup instead?

Comment: It depends on what it is you are trying to do. Is one character enough?...that would be satisfied by `keyup`...right?

Comment: Some HTML would probably be useful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

```
$('label').hide();

$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
  $('label').show();
});
```

BUT think about UX and accessibility: your users must be aware of what you expect them to input

Edit to display labels one at a time:

```
$('label').hide();

$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
  $(this).prev().show();
});
```

Comment: Well the placeholder has the same value of the label

Comment: -- that code will show ALL labels as soon as an input has been keyed up - as opposed to just the label prev to the input

Comment: I just edited the answer @TheOldCounty hope it'll help

Comment: $('label').css('visibility', 'hidden');

$('input').on('keyup', function(e){
  $(this).prev().css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('textarea').on('keyup', function(e){
  $(this).parent().prev().css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('select').on('change', function(e){
  $(this).parent().prev().css('visibility', 'visible');
});

Answer (score 1):

Would this work? ( pure css solution ) ( if you don't mind having label after input in html )

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
label { 
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
input:focus + label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input placeholder="Name">
  <label>Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: the drupal 8 webform structure though - has the label first, then the input